# Merge two columns and find corresponding name to another filed

Tags: sql

I have a table names "staff". This table has 10 columns: staffno, fname, lname, position, sex, dob, salary, branchno and manager. The column "manager" is the staffno of the persons manager if he/she has one, and NULL otherwise.

I want to find the name of each staff member and their manager too if they have one and merge the first name and last name in one column.

My code is as below:

```
SELECT CONCAT(staff.fname, ' ', staff.lname) AS StaffName ,
CONCAT(staff.fname, ' ', staff.lname) AS ManagerName
FROM staff WHERE staff.manager IS NOT NULL AND staff.staffno = staff.manager;
```

Is this code correct?

Comment: No. It only shows the firstname and lastname of the staff-member two times, if he/she has a manager.

Comment: When you are posting a question then use the proper tag.

Comment: I've removed all those dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `OUTER JOIN` :

```
CREATE TABLE staff(staffno int, manager int, fname varchar(25),lname varchar(25));
INSERT INTO staff VALUES(1,null,'John','Brown');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES(2,1,'Joe','Miller');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES(3,1,'Julia','Roberts');

SELECT CONCAT(s1.fname, ' ', s1.lname) AS ManagerName ,
       CONCAT(s2.fname, ' ', s2.lname) AS StaffName
  FROM staff s1 
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN staff s2
    ON s1.staffno = s2.manager
 ORDER BY COALESCE(s2.manager,0), s2.staffno; 

 ManagerName    StaffName
 -----------    -----------
                 John Brown
 John Brown      Joe Miller
 John Brown      Julia Roberts
```

The *SQL* above works for tagged databases such as `mysql`, `postgresql` and `sql-server`.

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/10987/7)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how we could consider the two conditions:

1- The name of a staff member if they have a manager
2- The name of the corresponding manager for the staff member?

Comment: @Farzad you're welcome. Depends on the column `ManagerName` to be null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this one:

```
SELECT CONCAT(staff.fname, ' ', staff.lname) AS StaffName,
CONCAT((SELECT fname FROM staff WHERE staff.staffno = staff.manager), ' ', (SELECT lname FROM staff WHERE staff.staffno = staff.manager)) AS ManagerName
FROM staff;
```